# Call a static method using a null instance

Tags: java

I was recently asked what is the output of the next code:

```
class MyClass {

   static void printMessage() {
      System.out.println("Hello from static");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyClass instance = null;
      instance.printMessage();
   }

}
```

**Output**

```
"Hello from static" without compile or runtime errors.
```

I know that static methods can be called using the name of the class such as *MyClass.staticMethod()* and also I know that you can call a static method inside a non-static one but the code above is confusing for me. Can anyone explain to me how is possible to call a static method using a null instance? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, because the compiler treats it as if it were written `MyClass.printMessage()` - the reference isn't used at all.

Comment: calling `static` methods on instances simply is a design flaw which can´t be removed due to backwards compatibility. It just works, because `instance` is defined as `MyClass` but the static call doesn´t mind the value assigned to it.

Comment: It's possible because the Java language designers decided to make that possible. It's now too late to fix that mistake, but you shouldn't call static methods that way anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.without instance of class we can access the static methods.MyClass.printMessage();

Comment: There is no need for an instance while invoking static member or method.
Since static members belongs to class rather than instance. so `instance.printMessage();` equal to `MyClass.printMessage()`

Comment: Hello guys. Thank you very much for all of your answers in such a short time. I'm still in the process of learning and these type of questions help me understand better what I can or can't do. Love you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You might think about `instance.printMessage();` when `printMessage()` is static as `instance.MyClass.printMessage();`

The real code is:

```
class MyClass{

   static void printMessage(){
     System.out.println("Hello from static");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass instance = null;
        instance.printMessage();
   }

 }
```

We can use imagination to make it easier to understand:

```
class MyClass{

   static void printMessage(){
     System.out.println("Hello from static");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass instance = null;
        instance.MyClass.printMessage();
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have got a warning at this line `instance.printMessage();` saying

> The static method printData() from the type
>   CallingStaticMethodOnNullReference should be accessed in a static way

So while compiling even if the method is called with or without `Class name`, the compiler will add the `Class name` along with the method call in the `.class` file like `MyClass.printMessage();`. That's why you are not getting any Exception. Sometimes code manipulation will be better if you think in compiler's perspective.